# How to decode this quiz code

Tags: base64, decode, encode

I've just started studying decode, and with a quiz sites. I think that they're base64 code and tried to decode in many decoded sites.
Ex: gPn8fA2pDJ9HApjA+Y9feV2RHTVv3l0BH6wDAH9CEh59vA5Q5RHT+UPOnHnwFn/R
How to decode them to ABCD and if you decode by a site, can you teach me how to use it? (only ABCD, because this's quiz site).
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the usage of Notepad++ to encode/decode Base64 data.
It is quite simple. Just navigate to menu Complements -> MIME Tools. Before clicking the encode/decode options, make sure you have selected the data you want to (en)(de)code. In Notepad++ you can open any type of files, even executables, PDF, etc, to use the Base64 capabilities.

Comment: You're welcome. Could you accept this as the right answer, please?